# Android Lock Screen Widget not Clickable

Tags: java, android, android-appwidget

I have made FlashLight widget. In home screen it's working perfect. When i add it as Lock Screen Widget it's shown but not turning on flashlight by clicking (or not clickable). Can anyone let me know , what mistake ma i doing? I am using HTC ONE m7 with KITKAT updated. Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is the code:

```
@Override

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId  = appWidgetIds[i];



            createWid(context,appWidgetManager,appWidgetId);

        }
    }

    private void createWid(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i0 = new Intent(); 

        i0.setAction("com.cookbook.SMSresponder.AEScreenOnOffService");
        context.  startService(i0);



        Intent receiver = new Intent(context, FlashlightWidgetReceiver.class);

        receiver.setAction("COM_FLASHLIGHT");
        receiver.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetId);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, receiver, 0);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.activity_smsr_responder);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonWidgetStopService, pendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
```